# How to prevent weird characters from showing up in web pages

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Often when outputting strings from a database onto a webpage, special characters get displayed as some other weird characters (in my example, an **em-dash** gets turned into **â€**“). How do I prevent this?

I'm using `PHP + MySQL`, and I'm not using any `frameworks`.

I'm guessing this is caused by mismatched encoding/charset between the HTML and the database, although I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Use char-set  UTF8 on HTML page as well as for DB also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html view page use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

and if you are inserting some other language character in place of english than make that column `utf8-general-ci`

Answer (score 3):

On top of your page in header tag use the below code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.Use following php inbuilt function to avoid those characters on given string. In your case, data from database.

```
html_entity_decode($given_string,ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake - This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8.
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  (It should have been `utf8`.)