# Escaping rare character output php

Tags: php

I have a php string which when displayed on the screen displays a symbol. $str

```
N�ME
```

i have tried

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")
```

and removes the string from the string completely. I have also tried

```
htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")
```

and it still completely removes the string from the output.

Comment: What is the character ?

Comment: Don't remove it blindly. Instead, try to figure out what character it is (printing an hexadecimal dump should help). I guess it isn't UTF-8 at all.

Comment: The [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) indicates that there was an error trying to parse the character. Removing it is a reasonable thing for `htmlspecialchars` to do. You should fix the error at source.

Comment: Most likely the problem is [in your database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484706/getting-weird-characters-when-fetching-value-in-mysql-database). Check to see if it's correctly stored in there, next make sure the charsets for your database are correct. The most commonly used is `utf8_unicode_ci`, make sure that both the database itself and its tables have this charset. Next also set the charset to `UTF-8` [in your HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340768/how-to-prevent-weird-characters-from-showing-up-in-web-pages).

Answer (score 0):

try

`regex()` for better result and it work

```
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $str);
```