# $.getJSON() + $.each() result in some object's key name undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json

Even though I've seen a lot of question related with this topic my problem seems to be different.

I better show an example to explain what my problem is:

```
var data = [
    {
        "Nº": 1,
        "Gasolina": "4,94",
        "Álcool": "4,28",
        "X": 397,
        "Y": -111
    },
    {
        "Nº": 2,
        "Gasolina": "4,10",
        "Álcool": "4,84",
        "X": -477,
        "Y": 101
    }
];

$.each(data, function (key, val) 
{
    console.log(val);
    console.log(val['Nº']);
    console.log(val['Gasolina']);
});

console.log("------------------------------");

// "data.json" contains the same info as the variable "data"
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) 
{
    $.each(data, function (key, val) 
    {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val['Nº']);
        console.log(val['Gasolina']);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
{NÂº: 1, Gasolina: "4,94", Ãlcool: "4,28", X: 397, Y: -111}
1
4,94
{NÂº: 2, Gasolina: "4,10", Ãlcool: "4,84", X: -477, Y: 101}
2
4,10
------------------------------
{Nº: 1, Gasolina: "4,94", Álcool: "4,28", X: 397, Y: -111}
undefined
4,94
{Nº: 2, Gasolina: "4,10", Álcool: "4,84", X: -477, Y: 101}
undefined
4,10
```

So my question is why do the key names "Nº" and "Álcool" behaves differently in both scenarios. After reading [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties) post I thought you could put almost anything as a key name. So why is "Nº" (and "Álcool") key names undefined when using `$.getJSON()` even though they're correctly printed in `console.log(val)`?

Note that this works in Nodejs. The problem only appears when I try to use this in HTML.

Comment: Because `NÂº != Nº`, i suspect both of your files are not using the same character encoding, ie UTF8, resave both to use the same encoding and test again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent weird characters from showing up in web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340768/how-to-prevent-weird-characters-from-showing-up-in-web-pages)

Comment: I can't believe how stupid I am. You were right, I forgot to add the UTF-8 meta in the html file. So simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add HTML encoding in your HTML file?

**For HTML 4**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

**For HTML5**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Add this `meta` tag inside your `head` tag in your `html file.`

Answer (score 1):

You have an encoding problem.

The `Á` char in UTF-8 appears as `Ã` in ISO-8859-1.

Your page is being served as UTF-8 and being displayed as ISO-8859-1.

Try escaping the char and you'll see:

```
// "data.json" contains the same info as the variable "data"
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) 
{
    $.each(data, function (key, val) 
    {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val['N\u00ba']);
        console.log(val['Gasolina']);
    });
});
```

Change the encoding of your page to `UTF-8`:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```